# React - value of a variable not changing properly

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a react app where I have to select a version of a phone and then confirm the newly selected version. Here is some code of the React component:

```
    constructor(props){
      super(props);
      this.toggleModal=this.toggleModal.bind(this);
      this.onChange=this.onChange.bind(this);
      this.handleSelect=this.handleSelect.bind(this);
      this.confirmChange=this.confirmChange.bind(this);
      this.newValue="";

  }

  newValue: string

  readonly state={
    "id": this.props.todo.id,
      "version": this.props.todo.version,
    "newVersion": ""
      }

  confirmChange(){
    this.setState({version:this.newValue});
  }

  onChange(e){
    this.newValue=e.target.value;
  }
```

Here the onChange is a function that gets triggered when a user selects a version, and the confirmChange function gets triggered when a user confirms the selection.
In the onChange event the e.target.value is the newly selected version, however when I try to access this.newValue variable, its value is: "" (empty string).
What could cause this kind of behavior?

Comment: What does the HTML look like? Do you create ist with JSX?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do in this way. 
Once the state has been updated, render will be called also you can get updated value of **newValue** in **confirmChange** function.

```
 constructor(props){
      super(props);
      this.toggleModal=this.toggleModal.bind(this);
      this.onChange=this.onChange.bind(this);
      this.handleSelect=this.handleSelect.bind(this);
      this.confirmChange=this.confirmChange.bind(this);
      this.state = {
        newValue : '',
        id: this.props.todo.id,
        version: this.props.todo.version,
       }
  }

  confirmChange(){
    this.setState({version:this.state.newValue});
  }

  onChange(e){
    this.setState({newValue: e.target.value});
  }
```

Comment: Didnt help. :( this.state.newValue is "" in the confirmChange function.

Comment: Are you sure you are getting value in e.target.value? 
Can you console it first and check?

Comment: I am 100% sure, I have checked it multiple times and the value is there.

Comment: Then in only one case it can be "" in this.state.newValue
confirmChange is getting called before change in newValue state. 
else it should work.

Answer (score 0):

You can set newVersion in state instead of this value.

If you want to work on the above solution you can check if there is value in e.target.value.

Happy coding!!

Comment: There is value in e.target.value. Setting the value in state doesnt help.